# How to get the desired output? 2 inputs given name and DOB?

Tags: javascript

2 inputs given name and DOB

Example.

Input 1: johndoe

Input 2: 08061972

Expected Output: j0o8h0n6d1o9e72

Comment: `let res="";
for(let i = 0;...) {res=res+input1[i]+input2[i]}`
This is the general idea. you'll need to take care of the length of each string and such.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```js
const garble = (name, dob) => {
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(name.length, dob.length); i++) {
    if (i < name.length) {
      result += name[i];
    }
    if (i < dob.length) {
      result += dob[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const expectedOutput = 'j0o8h0n6d1o9e72'
const actualOutput = garble("johndoe", "08061972");
console.log(actualOutput === expectedOutput, actualOutput);
```